# How to setup Ratchet Websocket server for production for Symfony 6 app on platform.sh

Tags: symfony, websocket, production-environment, ratchet, platform.sh

I am trying to setup a Ratchet Websocket server on my Symfony 6 app for production environment on platform.sh

Didn't find any reliable documentation about the subject, I have several questions :

1. According to https://docs.platform.sh/define-routes.html#websocket-routes I must define routes in `.platform/routes.yaml for websocket`, but I have actually no idea what values I should put there :

```yaml
"https://{default}/ws":  # is that some default route ? Should I set it in my app router too ?
    type: upstream
    upstream: "ws-app:http" # what exactly is ws-app ? Should I have a separated app ?
    cache:
        enabled: false
```

Knowing that locally the server works fine via  `ws://127.0.0.1:8080`

2. How to actually start the server in production ? Should I add something in my deploy scripts ?
   Should I use `RabbitMQ` or something similar ? Do I need a worker ?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Notice you posted here as well. Hopefully, we can get more eyes on the solution by me sharing the answer here as well.

```
"https://{default}/ws":
    type: upstream
    upstream: "ws-app:http"
    cache:
        enabled: false
```

Let's break this down.

1. `"https://{default}/ws":`

   - `https://` - since you don't have a `http://` route configured, `http://` will automatically redirect to `https://`.
   - `{default}` tells platform.sh to use your default domain assigned to the project. This is good to have in place, especially if you haven't attached a domain yet. That said, you could  type a static value such as `my-domain.com`
   - `/ws` - You're telling Platform.sh that any request to `/ws` (`https://{default}/ws`) should be handled by this route definition. If you're development  environment was sending websocket requests to `http://localhost/my/websocket`, you should replace `/ws` with `/my/websocket`. Use the path that your app is configured to work with.
2. `type: upstream` - normally you won't mess with this. This just let's Platform.sh know that we are going to direct this to the app that you have defined.
3. `upstream: "ws-app:http"`

   - This works with `type: upstream` to let Platform.sh know which app you want to answer this request.
   - `ws-app:http` - the first part of this is what matters—the `ws-app`. In your `.platform.app.yaml` or in your `.platform/applications.yaml` you will have defined an value like `name: app` or `name: my-symfony-app`. Whatever the value of `name:` is, that should be the first part of this value. In other words, if you use `name: my-websocket-app`, then in your routes.yaml you will use: `upstream: "my-websocket-app:http`

Once you have this route pointing to your websocket app, you will want to handle the next step, [request buffering](https://docs.platform.sh/define-routes.html#websocket-routes).